# How to update a row with a unique constraint? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

In my database, I have a row with these values:

| prop_1 | prop_2 | prop_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4444 | 'aaaa' | 'bbbb' |

This row has a unique constraint so that duplicate rows are not posted.

I want to update the value of the row to be:

| prop_1 | prop_2 | prop_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4444 | 'aaaa' | 'cccc' |

But when I use the 'UPDATE':

```
UPDATE table
SET prop_3 = 'cccc'
WHERE prop_1 = 4444
```

I get this error:

```
error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint_name"
...
detail: 'Key (prop_1, prop_3)=(4444, cccc) already exists.',
```

But I know for sure that that row does not exist with the value of 'cccc' for prop_3.

Also, I'm not inserting a new row, I just want to update an existing row.

How would I update an existing row in Postgresql with a unique constraint?

EDIT:

When I try this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE prop_3 = 'cccc'
```

0 rows / no rows are returned.

**Additional Edit:**

When I created this table originally, I think the way I set up the constraints was that I did not want another row to have the same exact matching values. I wanted to allow there to be duplicate values in rows, just not an exact duplicate of a row with the same 3 values.

I'm not sure how I set that up, it was so long ago.

I was thinking a potential solution would be to remove the unique constraint and create a new one the right way if I can't figure out how to update the current row.

Comment: Works well for me: See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uPB_kVXv). How is your UNIQUE constraint formed?

Comment: Please add the output of this statement to your question: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE prop_3 = 'cccc'`  (and the definition of that table (=DDL))

Comment: Then stil the DDL would be nice, to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: I've misplaced the DDL commands used to create the database table. Is there a way to check find the DDL commands used to create the table?

Comment: It's explained here how to do it in PostgreSQL: [Is there an equivalent of MySQL's SHOW CREATE TABLE in Postgres?](https://serverfault.com/questions/231952/is-there-an-equivalent-of-mysqls-show-create-table-in-postgres)

Comment: I think the way I created the constraints was to make it to where the combination of prop_1, prop_2, and prop_3 can never match. I'm not sure how I did that, it's been so long ago. Is it possible that prop_3 would not be able to be updated in this scenario if prop_1 and prop_2 still matched?

When I created it originally, I think I wanted it to be ok if there were multiple rows with the same value, just NOT with the exact same three values as another row.

Comment: Your update statement will attempt to set all rows with prop_1 of `4444` setting them to `cccc`. This is fine as long as only 1 row has prop_1 being `4444`. However, if there are 2 or more then the attempt updating the second will violate the unique constraint. Your query on `cccc` is then consistent as unique violation caused the updated rows to be rolled back. Check the following: `Select * from table where prop_1 = 4444;`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but when I changed my SQL UPDATE to:

```
UPDATE table
SET prop_3 = 'cccc'
WHERE prop_4 = 'another column row value'
```

It updated without any error.

Literally, all I changed was the WHERE value to another column in the row and the update worked without error. I don't know why that fixed it.

Comment: Probably because this statement updated other row(s), than the row you tried to update in your question ?

Comment: No, it updated the original row I was trying to update. I have no idea why changing the WHERE statement to check matching value in another column in the same row fixed it.

Comment: There could be a duplicate value somewhere I'm missing in the original call. I'm not sure